# Content in Slider doesn't fit on Mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile, responsive-design

I have a slider that shows the copy I've written along with a button which I would like to show up on the mobile version of the site. For some reason, the slider content does not adapt to the screen when I look at it on my phone.

The website is the following: www.luckywebsites.ca

Any tips on how to resize the slider for Mobile? If not, how can I make a separate site for the mobile only?

Comment: In which section of the website you have that problem?

Comment: Post some related code otherwise contact that website developer

Comment: Is ur issue about the first slide "You re lucky you found us..." is not displayed correct on mobile?
Checked that page on desktop and on mobile: on mobile the slider is fitting. It s just, that there is too much text for the first slide - or maybe the font-size is too large. Therefore the text is not fitting well.

Comment: @AbrahamLN In mobile you have to decrease some fonts size.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the size of the text font, check the font size and decrease it in mobile. Please check the screenshot taken after changing the font size. Modifying the code in main.min.css may do the work.

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
.btx-layout-responsive .font-style-big {
    font-size: 28px!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! Is there a way of changing the code to target specifically how things are seen on Mobile? I like the way the font looks when on the desktop and tablet.